# Converting between state.name and state.abb in R

Tags: r, maps

I am trying to add a column to my dataset that reads the state abbreviation and places the full name of the state (in lowercase) in the new column.  I have a dataset called Food that has the state abbreviation as a factor.  I ultimately want to map it using map_data("state").  map_Data("state") shows state abbreviations as a factor (called "region").  So I created a factor called region in my data frame.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
FoodSvc = read.csv("C:/Users/adam/FoodSrvcByCounty.csv")
food <- data.frame(FoodSvc)

all_states <- map_data("state")

food$region <- tolower(state.name[food$State])
food$region <- factor(food$region)


food_map_data <-  merge(all_states,food, by="region")
```

When I merge it, it seems to only be looking at the first character to map the abbreviation to the state name.  when I used the state.name[food$State] command.  Even though both are factors, it is treating the conversion as just one character.  So WV becomes Wyoming.

```
region      long      lat group order subregion     County State FoodServices.97 FoodServices.2002

921740 wyoming -109.0511 40.99513    63 15599      <NA>   Marshall    WV              61                61
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: How about `state.name[match(x,state.abb)]` ?

Comment: In the arc of your process is the long::any.state.name going to help you or just throw these confounds between you and mapping?

Comment: That is a good question & one I asked myself.  I'm doing a choropleth and the dataset has counties and states spelled out.  No lat/long.  So I am trying to merge it with the state map from library(maps).  I did try the match and got the same results.  I think it has something to do with the datatype, but can't see what.